# Redirect old uploads after moving to multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess

I have successfully moved the single site kitesista.com to a Multi-Site install (where it is a sub-domain) kite.sista.zone

I have 301 redirects for all urls however I need a rule to NOT redirect anything in the uploads folder to the new domain equivalent as I need to append /sites/3/ to the url.

This is what my htacees looks like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kitesista.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.kitesista.com [NC]

#not working redirect for uploads
RewriteRule ^(.*)wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://kite.sista.zone/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/$1 [L,R=301]

#working redirect for all traffic
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://kite.sista.zone/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

You can use this url to see it is not working: http://www.kitesista.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Crystal-Veness-BOTG-Prize.jpg ...and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you found any solution yet?